# how to load textfile of /stext out put to memo1

Tags: delphi

i am trying load file after it created from /stext command line but its not loading up

my code

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(path+'test.exe'), PChar('/stext "' + path + 'save.txt"'), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

after it created file i tried to load to memo1 from another button click

like

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(path+'save.txt');
end;
```

but its loading some unknown 3 characters

```
ÿþ=
```

**P.S : I opened manually it has real data of 30 lines :)**

why its happening ?

and one more thing is after i executed my first command shellexecute how i know that the file creation is done to load to my memo in same function without using sleep function :S

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see if this works

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(path+'save.txt', TEncoding.UTF8);
end;
```

because the first characters you posted I think are from the UTF8 encoding.

Also, to double check if it's the encoding. Try opening that file in notepad, and see if it's alright.

Comment: not worked and yeah i opened with note pad it has real data of 30 lines .

Comment: I don't know... could you provide the method which saves the file in the test.exe file, or put the 'save.txt' file into a zip and upload it somewhere so we can detect it's encoding (which seems to be the problem)

Comment: i dont think its encoing problem because file has so many characters but it displaying only 3 .

Comment: What I'm saying is that here might be some file header, where the fourth byte is a NULL and that's why your .LoadFromFile only loads the 3first chars

Comment: oh ic thanks for info sir 
anyway here u go one small file that generated 
http://www.xup.in/dl,12342219/save.rar/

Comment: Ok, so I downloaded your file, and here's some intresting stuff.

First of all, the .LoadFromFile with a single parameter (the filename) loads the file alright. Second, the file headers are $FF $FE which is an UTF-16 (TEncoding.Unicode) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

So I guess, your problem relies elsewhere, since you know, 'It works on MY machine', I'm also assuming you use Delphi 2009 or 2010

Comment: thanks for solution sir .i tested on delphi 2k9 and it worked . is there any solution that i can load that type of file in delphi 7 too ?

Comment: You can download http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=23&Itemid=33 library (from the author of VirtualStringTee) and use it in D7. I guess TWideStrings.LoadFrom file would do the trick (TWideStrings is a class in that library)

Comment: thanks bro ,btw what about other question , how i know that it completed in creating a file .